# How to sort the bibliography based on the order of citation in my text

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, bibliographystyle

I am trying to order my bibliography based on the order of citations in my text. Right now the bibliography order is probably based on the names of the authors. Because of that, my first citation in my Text is [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rH5BH.png), my second citation in my text is [3] and my third citation is [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SPV68.png).

I want the number in the citation bracket to correspond to the citation order in my text. The first citation has to be [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SPV68.png) the second citation [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rH5BH.png) and the third can be [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SPV68.png) if it's the same source as the first one.

I also noticed that my bibliography isn't numbered "Dr. Hans-Joachim Streitberger Prof. Dr. Artur Goldschmidt. BASF Handbuch Lackiertechnik. 2014. doi:
[https://doi.org/10.1515/9783748600398."](https://doi.org/10.1515/9783748600398.%22). How can I add a numbering in my bibliography (1. Dr. Hans...)

```
\documentclass[ 12pt,  ngerman,  onehalfspacing,  nolistspacing, 
parskip,  nohyperref,  consistentlayout,  ]{PSIThesis} 

\addbibresource{literatur_BA.bib}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=numeric-comp,
bibstyle=numeric]{biblatex}

\begin{document}

\newgeometry{   inner=2cm, % Inner margin   outer=2cm, % Outer margin
    marginparwidth=0cm,     marginparsep=0mm,   bindingoffset=.5cm, % Binding
offset  top=1.5cm, % Top margin     bottom=2.5cm, % Bottom margin,
    includehead,    includefoot     % showframe, % Uncomment to show how the
type block is set on the page }

\addchap{Literaturverzeichnis}

\printbibliography[heading=none]

\end{document}
```

[image: My bibliogrpahy right now]

[image: The first citaion must be 1]

Here I am going to add my .bib file:

```
@Book{Epoxidharze,   author    = {Michael Dornbusch und Ulrich Christ
und Rob Rasing},   year      = {2015},   booktitle = {Epoxidharze},  
doi       = {https://doi.org/10.1515/9783748600138},   file      =
{:D\:/Bachelorarbeit/Literatur/Bücher Verwenden/Dornbusch,
Christ et al 2015 - Epoxidharze.pdf:PDF}, }

@Book{Fink2013,   author    = {Johannes Karl Fink},   publisher =
{Elsevier},   year      = {2013},   abstract  = {Reactive Polymers
Fundamentals and Applications, Second Edition (2013) 95-153.
doi:10.1016/B978-1-4557-3149-7.00003-6},   booktitle = {Reactive
Polymers Fundamentals and Applications},   doi       =
{10.1016/b978-1-4557-3149-7.00003-6},   file      =
{:D\:/Bachelorarbeit/Literatur/Bücher Verwenden/Fink 2013 -
Epoxy Resins.pdf:PDF},   keywords  = {Monomers, Epoxides, Epoxy
resins, Antiplasticizers, Graphene, Photoinitiators, Epoxy systems,
Polymers, Epoxy-polyester resins, Optical resins},   pages     =
{95--153}, }

@Book{Gibson2017,   author    = {Geoff Gibson},   publisher =
{Elsevier},   year      = {2017},   abstract  = {Brydson's Plastics
Materials 773-797. 10.1016/B978-0-323-35824-8.00027-X},   booktitle =
{Brydson{\textquotesingle}s Plastics Materials},   doi       =
{10.1016/b978-0-323-35824-8.00027-x},   file      =
{:D\:/Bachelorarbeit/Literatur/Bücher Verwenden/Gibson 2017
- Epoxy Resins.pdf:PDF},   keywords  = {Acid anhydride, Amine, Bisphenol A, Composite materials, DGEBA, Epoxy, Oxirane},   pages    
= {773--797}, }

@Book{Lackeigenschaften,   author    = {Georg Meichsner und Thomas G.
Mezger und Jörg Schröder},   year      = {2016},   booktitle =
{Lackeigenschaften messen und steuern},   doi       =
{https://doi.org/10.1515/9783748600190},   file      =
{:D\:/Bachelorarbeit/Literatur/Bücher
Verwenden/Lackeigenschaften messen und steuern.pdf:PDF}, }

@Book{Lackformulierung,   author    = {Bodo Müller, Ulrich Poth},  
year      = {2017},   booktitle = {Bodo Müller Ulrich Poth},   doi    
= {https://doi.org/10.1515/9783748600206},   file      = {:D\:/Bachelorarbeit/Literatur/Bücher
Verwenden/Lackformulierung und Lackrezeptur.pdf:PDF}, }

@Book{Lackrohstoffkunde,   author    = {Paolo Nanetti},   year      =
{2017},   booktitle = {Lackrohstoffkunde},   doi       =
{https://doi.org/10.1515/9783748600213},   file      =
{:D\:/Bachelorarbeit/Literatur/Bücher Verwenden/Nanetti 2017
- Lackrohstoffkunde.pdf:PDF}, }

@Book{Handbuch,   author    = {Prof. Dr. Artur Goldschmidt, Dr.
Hans-Joachim Streitberger},   year      = {2014},   booktitle = {BASF
Handbuch Lackiertechnik},   doi       =
{https://doi.org/10.1515/9783748600398},   file      =
{:D\:/Bachelorarbeit/Literatur/Bücher Verwenden/Artur
Goldschmidt, Hans-Joachim Streitberger - BASF Handbuch Lackiertechnik]
BASF Handbuch.pdf:PDF}, }

@Book{Additivekompakt,   author    = {Bodo Müller},   year      =
{2009},   booktitle = {Additive kompakt},   doi       =
{https://doi.org/10.1515/9783748600114},   file      =
{:D\:/Bachelorarbeit/Literatur/Bücher Verwenden/Müller 2009
- Additive kompakt.pdf:PDF}, }

@Book{Koltzenburg,   author = {Sebastian Koltzenburg und Michael
Maskos und Oskar Nuyken},   file   = {:D\:/Bachelorarbeit
/Literatur/Bücher Verwenden/Koltzenburg, Maskos et al 2014 -
Polymere Synthese.pdf:PDF}, }

@Comment{jabref-meta: databaseType:bibtex;}
```

I found the "setup bibliography" section. Could this section maybe delete the numbers in the bibliography?

```
\setlength{\bibitemsep}{.3\baselineskip plus .05\baselineskip minus
.05\baselineskip} \newlength{\bibparskip}\setlength{\bibparskip}{0pt}
\let\oldthebibliography\thebibliography
\renewcommand\thebibliography[1]{%   \oldthebibliography{#1}%  
\setlength{\parskip}{\bibitemsep}%  
\setlength{\itemsep}{\bibparskip}% }

% allow much more liberal line breaks in URLs
\setcounter{biburllcpenalty}{7000} \setcounter{biburlucpenalty}{8000}

% adjust space between key and entry, default is 2\labelsep
\setlength{\biblabelsep}{1\labelsep}

% configures indentation of bibentries
\defbibenvironment{bibliography}   {\list
     {\hspace{0.5\labelalphawidth}\bfseries\printtext[labelalphawidth]{%
        \printfield{prefixnumber}%
        \printfield{labelalpha}%
        \printfield{extraalpha}}}
     {\setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{0.5\labelalphawidth}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{1.5\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}%
      \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{##1\hss}}   {\endlist}   {\item}
```

Comment: Hi! Where can we find `PSIThesis` class? Could you also add some example of `literatur_BA.bib`? Thank you!

Comment: https://github.com/UBA-PSI/psi-thesis-guide this is where i downloaded it from. Fyi i onyl sent a small part of the code and have changed some things from this PSIThesis template.

Comment: Please stick to one question at a time. That said, this has been asked & answered before. Usually using `\usepackage[style=numeric,sorting=none]{biblatex}` (note the `sorting=` parameter) is sufficient.

Comment: Off-topic: The keyword that separates authors in the author field should be `and`, not `und`.

Comment: @Mico is this going to be shown as and in my bibliography? I am writing my thesis in german.

Comment: @Abibo - *Au contraire*. Using `und` in the `author` field creates incorrect output. Only the use of `and` generates the correct output. Please see the answer I just posted.

Comment: Also off-topic: I can see no reasons for writing `{\textquotesingle}` instead of `'`. After all, it's just an apostrophe...

Comment: @Mico This is not my template. I dont know why the used that command.

Comment: @Abibo - It's your document, isn't it?

Comment: @Mico I am using a template. I am adjusting it where needed. If there are some functions which I dont need then I dont change there anything.

Comment: I trust you *will* see fit to change the field `booktitle = {Bodo Müller Ulrich Poth}`.

Comment: @Mico I did adjust my jabref entries. I used and instead of und. I fixed this. I also deleted the Prof. Dr.

Answer (score 2):

I used the `PSIThesis` from your link with `sorting=none` option in `biblatex` and I got this:

```
\documentclass[ 12pt,  ngerman,  onehalfspacing,  nolistspacing, 
parskip,  nohyperref,  consistentlayout,  ]{PSIThesis} 

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=numeric-comp,sorting=none,
bibstyle=numeric]{biblatex}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\setlength{\bibitemsep}{.3\baselineskip plus .05\baselineskip minus .05\baselineskip} \newlength{\bibparskip}\setlength{\bibparskip}{0pt} \let\oldthebibliography\thebibliography 
\renewcommand\thebibliography[1]{% 
    \oldthebibliography{#1}%
    \setlength{\parskip}{\bibitemsep}%
    \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibparskip}% 
    }

% allow much more liberal line breaks in URLs 
\setcounter{biburllcpenalty}{7000} \setcounter{biburlucpenalty}{8000}

% adjust space between key and entry, default is 2\labelsep 
\setlength{\biblabelsep}{1\labelsep}

% configures indentation of bibentries 
%\defbibenvironment{bibliography} {\list {\hspace{0.5\labelalphawidth}\bfseries\printtext[labelalphawidth]{% 
%\printfield{prefixnumber}% 
%\printfield{labelalpha}% 
%\printfield{extraalpha}}} {\setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}% 
%\setlength{\leftmargin}{0.5\labelalphawidth}% 
%\setlength{\itemsep}{1.5\bibitemsep}% 
%\setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}% 
%\renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{##1\hss}
%} {\endlist} {\item}

\addbibresource{literatur_BA.bib}

\begin{document}

\newgeometry{   inner=2cm, % Inner margin   outer=2cm, % Outer margin
    marginparwidth=0cm,     marginparsep=0mm,   bindingoffset=.5cm, % Binding offset 
    top=1.5cm, % Top margin     
    bottom=2.5cm, % Bottom margin,
    includehead,    includefoot     % showframe, % Uncomment to show how the type block is set on the page 
}

first citation \cite{Epoxidharze}
second citation \cite{Fink2013} 
third citation (first reapeated) \cite{Epoxidharze}
fourth citation \cite{Gibson2017}

\addchap{Literaturverzeichnis}

\printbibliography[heading=none]

\end{document}
```

Citations:

[image]

Bibliography:

[image]

The `literatur_BA.bib` that I used is (I corrected it as Mico pointed out):

```
@Book{Epoxidharze,   
   author    = {Michael Dornbusch and Ulrich Christ and Rob Rasing},   
   year      = {2015},   
   booktitle = {Epoxidharze},  
   doi       = {https://doi.org/10.1515/9783748600138},   
   file      = {:D\:/Bachelorarbeit/Literatur/Bücher Verwenden/Dornbusch, Christ et al 2015 - Epoxidharze.pdf:PDF}, 
}
@Book{Fink2013,   
   author    = {Johannes Karl Fink},   
   publisher = {Elsevier},   
   year      = {2013},   
   abstract  = {Reactive Polymers Fundamentals and Applications, Second Edition (2013) 95-153. doi:10.1016/B978-1-4557-3149-7.00003-6},   
   title     = {Reactive Polymers Fundamentals and Applications},   
   doi       = {10.1016/b978-1-4557-3149-7.00003-6},   
   file      = {:D\:/Bachelorarbeit/Literatur/Bücher Verwenden/Fink 2013 -
Epoxy Resins.pdf:PDF},   
   keywords  = {Monomers, Epoxides, Epoxy
resins, Antiplasticizers, Graphene, Photoinitiators, Epoxy systems,
Polymers, Epoxy-polyester resins, Optical resins},   
   pages     = {95--153}, 
}
@Book{Gibson2017,   
   author    = {Geoff Gibson},   
   publisher = {Elsevier},   
   year      = {2017},   
   abstract  = {Brydson's Plastics Materials 773-797. 10.1016/B978-0-323-35824-8.00027-X},  
   title     = {Brydson's Plastics Materials},   
   doi       = {10.1016/b978-0-323-35824-8.00027-x},   
   file      = {:D\:/Bachelorarbeit/Literatur/Bücher Verwenden/Gibson 2017
- Epoxy Resins.pdf:PDF},   
   keywords  = {Acid anhydride, Amine, Bisphenol A, Composite materials, DGEBA, Epoxy, Oxirane},   
   pages     = {773--797}, 
}
@Book{Lackeigenschaften,   
   author    = {Georg Meichsner and Thomas G. Mezger and Jörg Schröder},   
   year      = {2016},   
   title     = {Lackeigenschaften messen und steuern},   
   doi       = {https://doi.org/10.1515/9783748600190},   
   file      = {:D\:/Bachelorarbeit/Literatur/Bücher
Verwenden/Lackeigenschaften messen und steuern.pdf:PDF}, 
}
@Book{Lackformulierung,   
   author    = {Bodo Müller and Ulrich Poth},  
   year      = {2017},      
   doi       = {https://doi.org/10.1515/9783748600206},   
   file      = {:D\:/Bachelorarbeit/Literatur/Bücher Verwenden/Lackformulierung und Lackrezeptur.pdf:PDF}, 
}
@Book{Lackrohstoffkunde,   
   author    = {Paolo Nanetti},   
   year      = {2017},   
   title     = {Lackrohstoffkunde},   
   doi       = {https://doi.org/10.1515/9783748600213},   
   file      = {:D\:/Bachelorarbeit/Literatur/Bücher Verwenden/Nanetti 2017
- Lackrohstoffkunde.pdf:PDF}, 
}
@Book{Handbuch,   
   author    = {Artur Goldschmidt and Hans-Joachim Streitberger},   
   year      = {2014},   
   title     = {BASF Handbuch Lackiertechnik},   
   doi       = {https://doi.org/10.1515/9783748600398},   
   file      = {:D\:/Bachelorarbeit/Literatur/Bücher Verwenden/Artur
Goldschmidt, Hans-Joachim Streitberger - BASF Handbuch Lackiertechnik]
BASF Handbuch.pdf:PDF}, 
}
@Book{Additivekompakt,   
   author    = {Bodo Müller},   
   year      = {2009},   
   title     = {Additive kompakt},   
   doi       = {https://doi.org/10.1515/9783748600114},   
   file      = {:D\:/Bachelorarbeit/Literatur/Bücher Verwenden/Müller 2009
- Additive kompakt.pdf:PDF}, 
}
@Book{Koltzenburg,   
   author = {Sebastian Koltzenburg and Michael Maskos and Oskar Nuyken},   
   year = 2014,
   file   = {:D\:/Bachelorarbeit/Literatur/Bücher Verwenden/Koltzenburg, Maskos et al 2014 - Polymere Synthese.pdf:PDF}, 
}
```

As for the second question, the reason for the lack of numbering is this piece of code:

```
% configures indentation of bibentries
\defbibenvironment{bibliography}   {\list
     {\hspace{0.5\labelalphawidth}\bfseries\printtext[labelalphawidth]{%

    \printfield{prefixnumber}%
    \printfield{labelalpha}%
    \printfield{extraalpha}}}
 {\setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
  \setlength{\leftmargin}{0.5\labelalphawidth}%
  \setlength{\itemsep}{1.5\bibitemsep}%
  \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}%
  \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{##1\hss}}   {\endlist}   {\item}
```

Since you copy-pasted it without knowing what it does (no good idea) and you can't say what you need instead of it, just delete it.

Comment: Thank you very much. The sorting=none helped but for some reason my bibliography isnt numbered.

Comment: @Abibo We need a minimal example that reproduces your problem https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4407/how-to-write-a-mweb-minimal-working-example-with-bibliography. Without it, it is impossible to help you.

Comment: @Abibo Did you change anything else in the class?

Comment: I didnt change anything else in the \documentclass. I made a new test document wiht an article document class and there my bibliogrpahy is numbered. That means that there is one line of code in my template which deletes the numbers in my bibliogrpahy

Comment: I added a new block of code to my question, maybe the mistake is in there? But i doubt it. @CarLaTeX

Comment: No rush, when ever you find time you can take a look at it. I am really thankfull that you are helping me. I am new at latex ^^, but i have already solved quite a few problems

Comment: @Abibo The culprits are the instructions after `% configures indentation of bibentries`. If I comment that piece of code, the numbers appear in the bibliography. Why do you add them? What do you need exactly?

Comment: This is a template which I downloaded and I adjust it while writing my thesis. I have no idea why they added the code there. Now my bibliography is finally numbered. Thank you very much

Comment: @Abibo You're welcome!

Answer (score 2):

(too long for a comment, hence posted as an answer)

There are some significant errors in your bib entries. You really need to fix them -- in addition to worrying about sorting, or not sorting, the bibliographic entries by order of appearance of the citation call-outs. (To fix the latter issue, just add the option `sorting=none` while loading the `biblatex` pacckage. This has already been pointed out in @CarlaTeX's answer.)

For instance, quite a few of the `author` fields use `und` instead of `and` as the keyword to separate authors. Moreover, in at least two cases, a comma is used instead of the keyword `and`.

The offending fields are:

```
author    = {Michael Dornbusch und Ulrich Christ und Rob Rasing},   
author    = {Georg Meichsner und Thomas G. Mezger und Jörg Schröder},   
author    = {Bodo Müller, Ulrich Poth},
author    = {Sebastian Koltzenburg und Michael  Maskos und Oskar Nuyken},
```

and, for crying out loud,

```
author    = {Prof. Dr. Artur Goldschmidt, Dr. Hans-Joachim Streitberger},
```

An author's academic titles do not, *under any circumstance*, belong in the `author` field. Period. No exception.

These fields should be

```
author    = {Michael Dornbusch and Ulrich Christ and Rob Rasing},   
author    = {Georg Meichsner and Thomas G. Mezger and Jörg Schröder},   
author    = {Bodo Müller and Ulrich Poth},
author    = {Sebastian Koltzenburg and Michael Maskos and Oskar Nuyken}, 
author    = {Artur Goldschmidt and Hans-Joachim Streitberger},
```

---

In case you don't believe me: If you persist in setting `author = {Michael Dornbusch und Ulrich Christ und Rob Rasing},` the author field will get typeset as

[image]

In contrast, with `author = {Michael Dornbusch and Ulrich Christ and Rob Rasing},` you'll get

[image]

Likewise, `author = {Bodo Müller, Ulrich Poth}` generates

[image]

whereas `author = {Bodo Müller and Ulrich Poth},` generates

[image]

---

There's still another major issue: for entries of type `@book`, the book's title should be given in the field `title`, *not* in the field `booktitle`.

Applying these fixes is *not optional*.

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrbook} %{PSIThesis} 

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{literatur_BA.bib}
@Book{Epoxidharze,   
   author    = {Michael Dornbusch and Ulrich Christ and Rob Rasing},   
   year      = {2015},   
   booktitle = {Epoxidharze},  
   doi       = {https://doi.org/10.1515/9783748600138},   
   file      = {:D\:/Bachelorarbeit/Literatur/Bücher Verwenden/Dornbusch, Christ et al 2015 - Epoxidharze.pdf:PDF}, 
}
@Book{Fink2013,   
   author    = {Johannes Karl Fink},   
   publisher = {Elsevier},   
   year      = {2013},   
   abstract  = {Reactive Polymers Fundamentals and Applications, Second Edition (2013) 95-153. doi:10.1016/B978-1-4557-3149-7.00003-6},   
   title     = {Reactive Polymers Fundamentals and Applications},   
   doi       = {10.1016/b978-1-4557-3149-7.00003-6},   
   file      = {:D\:/Bachelorarbeit/Literatur/Bücher Verwenden/Fink 2013 -
Epoxy Resins.pdf:PDF},   
   keywords  = {Monomers, Epoxides, Epoxy
resins, Antiplasticizers, Graphene, Photoinitiators, Epoxy systems,
Polymers, Epoxy-polyester resins, Optical resins},   
   pages     = {95--153}, 
}
@Book{Gibson2017,   
   author    = {Geoff Gibson},   
   publisher = {Elsevier},   
   year      = {2017},   
   abstract  = {Brydson's Plastics Materials 773-797. 10.1016/B978-0-323-35824-8.00027-X},  
   title     = {Brydson's Plastics Materials},   
   doi       = {10.1016/b978-0-323-35824-8.00027-x},   
   file      = {:D\:/Bachelorarbeit/Literatur/Bücher Verwenden/Gibson 2017
- Epoxy Resins.pdf:PDF},   
   keywords  = {Acid anhydride, Amine, Bisphenol A, Composite materials, DGEBA, Epoxy, Oxirane},   
   pages     = {773--797}, 
}
@Book{Lackeigenschaften,   
   author    = {Georg Meichsner and Thomas G. Mezger and Jörg Schröder},   
   year      = {2016},   
   title     = {Lackeigenschaften messen und steuern},   
   doi       = {https://doi.org/10.1515/9783748600190},   
   file      = {:D\:/Bachelorarbeit/Literatur/Bücher
Verwenden/Lackeigenschaften messen und steuern.pdf:PDF}, 
}
@Book{Lackformulierung,   
   author    = {Bodo Müller and Ulrich Poth},  
   year      = {2017},      
   doi       = {https://doi.org/10.1515/9783748600206},   
   file      = {:D\:/Bachelorarbeit/Literatur/Bücher Verwenden/Lackformulierung und Lackrezeptur.pdf:PDF}, 
}
@Book{Lackrohstoffkunde,   
   author    = {Paolo Nanetti},   
   year      = {2017},   
   title     = {Lackrohstoffkunde},   
   doi       = {https://doi.org/10.1515/9783748600213},   
   file      = {:D\:/Bachelorarbeit/Literatur/Bücher Verwenden/Nanetti 2017
- Lackrohstoffkunde.pdf:PDF}, 
}
@Book{Handbuch,   
   author    = {Artur Goldschmidt and Hans-Joachim Streitberger},   
   year      = {2014},   
   title     = {BASF Handbuch Lackiertechnik},   
   doi       = {https://doi.org/10.1515/9783748600398},   
   file      = {:D\:/Bachelorarbeit/Literatur/Bücher Verwenden/Artur
Goldschmidt, Hans-Joachim Streitberger - BASF Handbuch Lackiertechnik]
BASF Handbuch.pdf:PDF}, 
}
@Book{Additivekompakt,   
   author    = {Bodo Müller},   
   year      = {2009},   
   title     = {Additive kompakt},   
   doi       = {https://doi.org/10.1515/9783748600114},   
   file      = {:D\:/Bachelorarbeit/Literatur/Bücher Verwenden/Müller 2009
- Additive kompakt.pdf:PDF}, 
}
@Book{Koltzenburg,   
   author = {Sebastian Koltzenburg and Michael Maskos and Oskar Nuyken},   
   year = 2014,
   file   = {:D\:/Bachelorarbeit/Literatur/Bücher Verwenden/Koltzenburg, Maskos et al 2014 - Polymere Synthese.pdf:PDF}, 
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[backend=biber, 
            style=numeric-comp, 
            bibstyle=numeric,
            sorting=none
           ]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{literatur_BA.bib}

\usepackage{xurl}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[heading=none]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much.